# Derivative of $y$. Where $y$ is the solution of one ecuation.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, where $x^3-3xy^3+x^2+y^2+7=0$
How am I supposed to extract $y$ as a function of $x$ fom that equation? Thank you!

Comment: Is this from a chapter on implicit differentiation by any chance?

Comment: I don't know exactly where it is from. It is from an exam...so can't tell!

Comment: Okay let me rephrase: you have to use implicit differentiation.

Comment: These downvoters really annoy me: it is obvious that the OP doesn't know that the problem is solved with implicit differentiation, so he is painfully and mistakenly looking to express $y$ as a function of $x$. Mathematicians are supposed to be intelligent and to be able to read between the lines, but I don't see this in all this downvoting.

Comment: @DenisNichita: So far you have asked 16 questions but only accepted 2 answers. On behalf of the Math.SE users, I apologize for us not being up to your level of excellence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that we have $$y=y(x)$$ then we get by differentiating with respect to $x$
$$3x^2-3y^3-3x\cdot 3y^2\cdot y'+2x+2y\cdot y'=0$$

Comment: Where did you get $-3x3y^2y'$ and $2yy'$?

Comment: @DenisNichita As I had said before two times, implicit differentiation